# IF + VLOOK UP give me #N/A. Can't return the values

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

There are 2 tables. I want to look into the second table and find companies that report the amount of income that does not match information we have on hand and list the wrong amounts in column D. I use if with VLOOKUP. It does catch the companies that report the unmatched amount, but I can't find the way to return the amount they reported in column D. My formula is

=IF(C6=VLOOKUP(B6,$F$4:$G$19,2,FALSE),"",C6=VLOOKUP(C6,$F$4:$G$19,2,FALSE))

I attached the picture of what I have so far here. Please help. Thank you.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZKg2q.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want:

```
=IF(C6=VLOOKUP(B6,$F$4:$G$19,2,FALSE),"",VLOOKUP(B6,$F$4:$G$19,2,FALSE))
```

?

Your problem is in the else clause of your If statement. It is looking for the value that you have on hand for the companies where the values that don't match (so it is pretty unlikely that it will find that anywhere in the second table, and if it does it will be a mistake) and then checking if the value returned by VLOOKUP (which probably is N/A) is equal to the value that you have on hand.

Comment: Thank you very much. I fixed it. It is =IF(C4=VLOOKUP(B4,$F$4:$G$19,2,FALSE),"",VLOOKUP(B4,$F$4:$G$19,2,FALSE)). I really appreciate your help.

Comment: @BJulie -- if this answer led you to the solution, you should mark it as "accepted" so future people with similar issues will know your question has a solution

Answer (score 0):

```
=IF(IFERROR(C6=VLOOKUP(B6,$F$4:$G$19,2,FALSE),"")=TRUE,C6,"")
```